# Update state object with multiple keys using input id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-state

my state looks like this:

`const [options, setOptions] = useState({ numbers: false, animals: false, greetings: false, food: false, colors: false, other: true })`

and I'm trying to update a single boolean based on a checkbox.

At first I used a switch statement like so:

```
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'numbers': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, numbers: e.target.checked })); break;
      case 'animals': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, animals: e.target.checked })); break;
      case 'greetings': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, greetings: e.target.checked })); break;
      case 'food': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, food: e.target.checked })); break;
      case 'colors': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, colors: e.target.checked })); break;
      case 'other': setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, other: e.target.checked })); break;
      default: break
    }
```

but I think as I add more options, I'll want something cleaner, I was hoping something like

`setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, options[e.target.id]: e.target.checked }))`

would work but no luck. I also tried

`options[e.target.id] = e.target.checked`

but it doesn't do a refresh.

Comment: Just remove `options` from `options[e.target.id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *cleaner* version is definitely the preferred one but the syntax for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) is

```js
{
  [ key ]: value
}
```

I'd be inclined to use a `name` attribute instead of `id`, mainly to avoid accidentally duplicating IDs.

```js
const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
  setOptions(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
  }));
};
```

You just need to make sure your checkbox elements have appropriate attributes

```jsx
{Object.entries(options).map(([option, checked]) => (
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name={option}
      checked={checked}
      onChange={handleCheckbox}
    />
    {option}
  </label>
))}
```

Comment: Ahhh of course, `[e.target.name]: e.target.checked` not `options[e.target.id]: e.target.checked` thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute with each checkbox and this name should a valid key from options.

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({ numbers: false, animals: false, greetings: false, food: false, colors: false, other: true })

const handleStateChange = (e)=>{
const {name,value} = e.target
setOptions(preState => ({...preState ,[name]:value}))
}

<input type='checkbox' name='numbers' value={options.numbers} onChange={handleStateChange} />
<input type='checkbox' name='animals' value={options.animals} onChange={handleStateChange} />
<input type='checkbox' name='greetings' value={options.greetings} onChange={handleStateChange} />
```